# oracle sql developer changing currency

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Can  I know like if I want to change the currency in Oracle using sql statement?

How I could do that as when I use `TO_CHAR (budget 'MYR99,999.00')` not working but `TO_CHAR (budget, '$99,999.00')` it appears as `$`. I want in RM, so, I key in `myr`, not working.

Is there any solution that you like to share to solve this problem?

Comment: But what is "MYR" Is it your currency? `TO_CHAR (budget , 'C99,999.00')`. and more info about to_char [FORMAT MODEL](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00210)

Comment: yup MYR is malaysian ringgit which is RM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first set up your locale, either on the DB-session level for your currency only ...

```
alter session set nls_iso_currency = 'MALAYSIA';
```

... or on the level of your client environment (Windows? Unix? whatever?) as the `NLS_LANG` environment variable ...

```
# on Unixes ...
export NLS_LANG=english_MALAYSIA.al32utf8
```

... and then you could use the correct format modifiers ...

```
select to_char(budget, 'fmC99G999D00', 'nls_numeric_characters=''.,''')
from dual;
```

**Explanation of the format:**

- `fm` strips the leading spaces
- `C` is for uppercase currency based on your locale
- `G` is for the thousands grouping symbol
- `D` is for the fractional part separator

Answer (score 1):

Using SQL Statement, then ALTER SESSION SET would suffice. If you want to change these settings for your sessions going forward in the tool, then you can do so in the preferences.

[image: Configuring NLS Params in SQL Developer]

Comment: thanks. for helping.. i try this and see. but is there any way that i can use the sql statement instead of GUI.

Comment: of course, ALTER SESSION SET...will do the same thing. If you open in version 4.1 the log, statements panel, on login you will see SQLDev issue those to reflect the settings listed above.